# SSIS Excel source with more then 255 characters

Tags: ssis

I need help with a problem. I am using SSIS package within Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 to transfer data to MSSQL server. I have a lot of data in xlsx format that I need to transfer to a database. I usually transfer data from multiple xlsx files into one table, for which I use Foreach Loop Container. I repeatedly run into problems with column sizes and data types. Specifically, when a single column, for example "NOTE" in one file contains text that is less than 255 characters and more than 255 characters in the other file, therefore it should be transferred in DT_NTEXT format. Whenever an SSIS package encounters a file during transmission that does not match the initial input format the package will crash. I have tried many ways to solve this, none have worked. The only thing that helps is to add an artificial line at the first position in the xlsx file, which will always have more than 255 characters in the "NOTE" column. However, this is a very impractical solution. I have to open all the files and in a large number it takes a lot of time. I find this to be a major shortcoming of SSIS.

Has anyone solved this problem? Can you advise a better solution please?

Comment: You can go into advanced settings of the data flow task, Right click the source, go to advanced settings, Then go to input and output properties, and go to output columns, and find the column and you can change the data type there so it wont look at what is in Excel but use what you set.